# Start Sagemaker Notebook Instances - Question

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

Quick question regarding the start/boot up on a existing sagemaker notebook instance. I previously created a notebook instance, and shut it down when I stop using it. I was giving access to this shared account by a co-worker who manages our AWS infrastructure, and this account is shared to multiple members from other departments, but then he gave me a separate sandbox account, where I'm the only one using.

After one month, I went back to that same account (shared one) and found out my notebook instance, along side others, were running. Not sure how, and why. I'm pretty sure I turned them off (at least mine), and no other person uses them, or uses Sagemaker.

Is there any possible way that these notebook instances started by chance, or other possible explanation to it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick way to diagnose this would be using [CloudTrail](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/). Go to the CloudTrail console in the shared account, choose "Event History" section on the left. You can then filter by "Event name": "StartNotebookInstance" and you'll be able to see which identity made the call.

Afaik, no AWS service would automatically start a notebook instance.

Comment: Thanks for this. I dig around with Cloudtrial, and I was able to see all my actions and others people as well from Sage maker. Thanks!